# Excel makes a mistake at paste special - number only

Tags: microsoft-excel, copy-paste

Excel (Office 365) is making a strange error when pasting numbers only:

cell A1 value = 1727979.28
cell A2 value = 1678319.54
cell A3 formula = (A2 - A1) -> result = -49659.74

if I select&copy A3 and paste special (values only) to A4 the value in A4 = -49659.7399999999 ?!?

Is this expected bahaviour or some setting I can change?

Comment: It's not formatting, the values (if you look inside the cells) are exactly as I typed above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not a mistake. It's all about how Excel stores such numbers, in this case in point `float` number variables, which can be seen as [Scientific Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) and a division of numbers. This division is an aproximation of the real number, in you case `49659.74` so it's going to get stored as a compact division that can generate a "string" of numbers like that and then it's going to place the decimal point, that's where the scientific notation comes around.

For a machine `-49659.74` and `-49659.7399999999`, are pretty much the same. And for most cases it's good enough. If you need to use only two decimals, sorround your formula with `=round(YOUR_FORMULA;2)` this way your number will get rounded to two decimal.

[It's addressed by Microsoft Here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2008/04/10/understanding-floating-point-precision-aka-why-does-excel-give-me-seemingly-wrong-answers/) How Excel handles decimal number.

Cheers