# Microsoft Excel Is changing cell values

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

Three cells in a spreadsheet are deliberately changing their values (rounding off, essentially). For e.g., a cell which is supposed to read 9969001500006276 gets converted to 9969001500006270, later when I reopen excel, I find the number as 9969001500006280.

I have tried increasing decimal spaces and changing number formats and enlarging cell size.
I have even tried to remove the column altogether and recreate it.
I have also tried editing in Google Sheets and SoftMaker FreeOffice and (guess what) I got the same results.

The problem is repetitive only with the three cells and other cells seem to function well enough. 
*(I am a complete amateur with spreadsheets. And, I use Office 2016.)*

Comment: Excel only use 15 significant digits, and rounds off the rest.  If you want to "show" more then you need to save the number as text and not a true number.

Comment: @ScottCraner Even I thought that to be the case. But that doesn't appear to work either. Excel seems hellbent on keeping the cells in its own ways and customs and traditions. Another significant fact is that there are other cells that have numbers even larger than these (most of them in the 'General' or 'Number' cell format) and excel is fine with these others.

Comment: Just because it is formatted as general or number does not mean it is not text.  Text will remain the same if no matter the **NUMBER** format.  It could appear as a number but be saved as text.

Comment: @ScottCraner No. No. No. I do understand what you mean. I only mean that I tried using general and number formats after I had experimented with the text format. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Thanks everybody. You all saved me from breakneck times. I you think it appropriate, this question may now be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer:**
Bank account numbers are just an "identification", not something you would use in a mathematical formula. Enter these with a leading `'` and Excel WILL NOT change them anytime.  (This is equal to an UNCONDITIONAL "TEXT" formatting)

**Background information:**
As @Scott Craner says, for numbers there is a **16** digit precision limitation - due to the way that NUMBERS are used in a computer *(i.e. 64 bit floating point format, also known as "double precision")*.
To get past that limit one must use special tricks and utilities - IF IT IS INDEED a NUMBER, to be used for e.g. calculations.

The linux command line calcuator [`bc`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bc) is one such utility, and e.g. [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663272/double-precision-floating-values-in-python) has several ways to handle high precision numbers.

Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format
*"Between 2^52=4,503,599,627,370,496 and 2^53=9,007,199,254,740,992 the representable numbers are exactly the integers. For the next range, from 2^53 to 2^54, everything is multiplied by 2, so the representable numbers are the even ones, etc. Conversely, for the previous range from 25^1 to 2^52, the spacing is 0.5, etc. "*

**In depth explanation:**
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Answer (score 0):

this behavior is to be expected. It is due to the way numbers like that gets stored inside SpreadSheets. Every cell is container of some data and metadata. Like when you store a date, sometimes you will see it as a number such `43475` when there is no format applied, then you will go and ask for a short date format and it will be displayed as `10/01/2019`. So compromised had to be made in order to fit said data and metadata, for those cells in every spreadsheet.

Then about the number I have addressed this in [This Answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1385190/excel-makes-a-mistake-at-paste-special-number-only/1385230#1385230) Numbers are stored in float point number variables, which you can read more about [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format), are like a division and scientific notation. It will generate the string of numbers and then it will place the decimal in place. So the last couple of numbers are not that precise, because of rounding up the last digits.

Comment: I very much get your point but I confused Excel should let some cells (with even larger numbers) retain their original values but not the three. I believe, so far anyway, that I might have accidentally triggered some formula that affects only the three victim cells. Also , I am quite desperately looking for a solution to thisñ

Comment: @PlytonRexus It's not about Excel stripping away something. It's about how numbers get stored inside Excel and then showing them to you. May I ask, What are you working with? Maybe you need other tools.

Comment: Sure. The spreadsheet is a simple list of bank A/C numbers. It is not heavily formatted but has many merged cells and text rotations. Might you need anything else? I just don't understand why Excel will store a number in one cell in a way different from others when all of them contain the same data. Thanks for the quick response by the way.

Comment: @PlytonRexus It's _possible_ (I've not tested it) that for _really_ big "numbers" Excel isn't trying to store them as numbers, and just stores them directly as text. Your "problem" numbers may be small enough for Excel to try and store them as numbers, but large enough to get errors due to limited precision.

Comment: Thanks TripeHound. That might indeed be possible. But anyway, @Hannu's way seems to have bypassed whatever problem had crept in. Thanks again, though.